# codeigniter Array to string conversion error during form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I am getting a strange error for the first time. I'm trying to validate a form

**my code**

```
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $oppTitle       = $this->input->post('oppTitle');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('oppTitle','Title','required|max_length[100]|xss_clean');


 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ){
      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
      $this->load->view('admin/addopportunitypage',$data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
    }               
 else
   {
      // insert code
   }
 }
```

**Error message**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: core/Lang.php
>
> Line Number: 111
>
> **Unable to load the requested language file: language/Array/form_validation_lang.php**

Comment: What is `$data` over here..

Comment: You must add your language file on lang folder. You can copy English file for form_validation_lang.php and translate it or if file created by your-own, you must create and insert lang coded to it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with language...i dont get it

Comment: Can you provide us with your, `$config['language']` from `application/config.php` ?

Comment: $config['language'] = 'english';

Comment: Seems like something is overwriting your language config then. Try dumping the return value of `get_config()`

Comment: Dude...thank you so much man...U saved my time. I actually created a config variables with config['language'], that conflicted withn the CI's config..Now I changed the variable name and everything is working fine..